# How to make marks draggable on vue-slider-component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi i want to drag `marks` of `vue-slider-component` but drag is not happening

I have 2 marks which is

1. - M1 Dragg me
2. - M2 Dragg me

here is how my marks will look like

```
 marks: {
          '600': {label: ' - M1 Dragg me', draggable: true },
          '2000': {label: ' - M2 Dragg me', draggable: true},
        }
```

here is what i have tried

```css
@import 'vue-slider-component/theme/default.css';
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://nightcatsama.github.io/vue-slider-component/dist/index.js"></script>

<template>
  <div>
    <VueRangeSlider v-model="value" v-bind="options" :marks="marks"></VueRangeSlider>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

new Vue({
    components: {
      // eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-unused-components
      VueRangeSlider
    },
    data(){
      return {
        value: [0,1200],
        options:{min:0,max:3000},
        marks: {
          '600': {label: ' - M1 Dragg me', draggable: true },
          '2000': {label: ' - M2 Dragg me', draggable: true},
        },
        dragInfo: null,
      }
    },
    methods: {
      handleMarkMouseDown(markKey, event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.dragInfo = {
          markKey: markKey,
          startPosition: event.pageX,
          startValue: this.marks[markKey],
        };
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMarkMouseMove);
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.handleMarkMouseUp);
      },
      handleMarkMouseMove(event) {
        if (!this.dragInfo) {
          return;
        }
        const deltaX = event.pageX - this.dragInfo.startPosition;
        const stepSize = this.options.step || 1;
        const newValue = Math.round(this.dragInfo.startValue + (deltaX / this.$refs.slider.clientWidth) * (this.options.max - this.options.min) / stepSize) * stepSize;
        if (newValue < this.options.min || newValue > this.options.max) {
          return;
        }
        this.$set(this.marks, this.dragInfo.markKey, {label: this.dragInfo.startValue.label, draggable: true, value: newValue});
      },
      handleMarkMouseUp(event) {
          console.log(event);
        if (!this.dragInfo) {
          return;
        }
        this.dragInfo = null;
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMarkMouseMove);
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.handleMarkMouseUp);
      },
    },
  })
</script>
```